# Dynamically set target when making API calls in REACT

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I am building a multi-tenant web site with React Js and Django.

This is my **setupProxy.js** file:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api/products',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://tenant1.localhost:8000',
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
    })
  );
};
```

This works but I need the target value to be 'http://tenant1.localhost:8000' or 'http://tenant2.localhost:8000'or 'http://tenant3.localhost:8000' etc... depending on the subdomain or tenant.

The idea is to get the subdomain from the URL - for example http://tenant1.localhost:3000.

Would anyone have an idea of how I could accomplish this?

As an additional note, this is how I invoke the API request:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Product from '../components/Product'

import axios from 'axios'

function HomeScreen() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])  /* const[state, method] */

    useEffect(() => {

        async function fetchProducts(){
            const { data } = await axios.get('api/products/')
            setProducts(data)
        }

        fetchProducts()

    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Latest Products</h1>
            <Row>
                {products.map(product => (
                    <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                        <Product product={product} />
                    </Col>
                ))}
            </Row>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found an initial solution:

setupProxy.js:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

function customRouter(req) {
  const { hostname } = req
  const tenant = hostname.split('.')[0]
  return `http://${tenant}.localhost:8000`
}

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api/products',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      router: customRouter,
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
    })
  );
  app.use(
    '/media/*',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      router: customRouter,
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
    })
  );
};
```

I got this from [here](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/200#issuecomment-776376844). I am extremely new to React JS and so I don't really know if this is a good solution. Also, I still need to find a way to route localhost:3000 successfully...